# set npm proxy without using http:// before the proxy server name

Tags: node.js, npm

I have npm installed and have used it a few times but unfortunately I had to change my proxy and I am not able to get it to work again.

here are my past settings:(the ones that worked)

npm config get proxy: `http://proxy-foo.foobar.com:8080`

npm config get https-proxy: `http://proxy-foo.foobar.com:8080`

now my proxy is a server name and when I use the proxy in my browser it works fine, but when I set the config in npm it fails with 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND'

current settings:

npm config get proxy: `http://servername:8080`

npm config get https-proxy: `http://servername:8080`

in my browsers proxy I do not use http:// before the server name and I think this is what is causing it to fail. could this be the problem and if so is there a way to set proxy configs in npm without using http:// before.

Comment: npm doesn't care if it has the http:// or not. What OS? Do other command-line utilities (e.g. git, wget) work OK through the proxy?

Comment: I was able to get it to work by using the FQDN instead of just the server name, and from my experience NPM does care about the http:// before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right; `npm` (more accurately, `request`, which actually does the fetching) **does** care about the `http://` before the proxy name.

The `proxy` setting should be a fully-qualified URL that you could visit in a browser, e.g.,

`http://proxy.company.com:port/`

or

`http://1.1.1.1:1234/`

if specified as an IP address.